# How to work with layers in 2.9x like in previous versions (2.7x)

Tags: layers

I'm trying to learn Blender using version 2.9.  I'm watching a tutorial from Blender Guru, Andrew Price, in which he uses an earlier version (tutorial made 2017).  This is the Anvil tutorial.  However I am trying to "interpret" what Andrew is doing on his version and how to do the same on 2.9.

A prime example of this is Layers.  In his Anvil tutorial he makes a duplicate anvil and places it on a spare layer for use later on in the "bake".  This allows him to work on the first layer and keep the other for later.(High poly and low poly version)
In 2.9 I have found the box with layers in the top right.  I have tried copying to a new layer, but when I sculpt on the original one it changes the other layer too, which can't be the aim.
I can't seem to create the same actions in the latest version and run two distinct layers with different info on each.

Comment: Hello :) Andrew updated the [Donut tutorial for 2.8 interface](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U). You may find it a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 3):

The 2.7 *Layers* have been replaced by [*Collections*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/), you should now use *Collections*. Basically one former *Layer* is now one *Collection* (and when you open an old Blender file *Layers* are automatically replaced by *Collections*).

[image]

You're confusing *Layers* with *View Layers*, which are completely different things, *View Layers* are useful for the *Compositor* (which is not the case in this tutorial).

With *View Layers* you're just changing the visibility settings of the current scene for later compositing purpose, so when you modify an object, it's the exact same object as the one of another *View Layer*.